# Scraping with Beautiful Soup-getting empty set

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code but still keep getting an empty set. Any ideas?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests, time, os,html5lib

base_site = "https://www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard/_/year/2019/seasontype/2/week/14"
response = requests.get(base_site)
soup = bs(response.text,"html.parser")
soup

# Find all links on the page 
game = soup.find_all("section", class_="sb-score.final")
game
```

Here is what I'm seeing on the site:
[image]

Comment: Shouldnt it be class_="sb-score final" ? you have a . instead of space

Comment: @ Blaine: Good catch. I tried:  game = soup.find_all("section", class_="sb-score final") and still got an empty set.  Thanks

Comment: are you sure the response you are getting in Python is what you are looking at on the site?  Sometimes sites catch spiders and send them to a different page.

Comment: try debugging by logging the entire response.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that there are multiple classes, you could try:

```
find_all('section', class_=['sb-score', 'final'])
```

Comment: @ Micara: Thank you. I tried:
game = soup.find_all("section", class_=["sb-score", "final"])   and still get an empty set.

Comment: @DJF And have you tried doing response.content as opposed to response.text?

Comment: @ Micara: Yes, text was my second try.  Thanks